# How do I set up an external build tool (make) within XCode3?

Tags: xcode, makefile, xcode3.2

I've used XCode4 for a large C++ project. The project uses make for build. I've set up XCode4 to use external build tool make so that my Makefile is called each time I hit build and I see compile errors nicely within XCode.

First, this worked OK but recently XCode4 crashes a lot. Now I am switching back to XCode3 but I cannot find out how to set up build using an external build tool in XCode 3.2.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but when I'm ready to build an external static framework I use a bunch of scripts I have written and you can see at [my Github repo](https://github.com/drekka/dUsefulStuff). Look in the scripts directory and at the build.sh which configures and calls them.

I've used these scripts on both XCode 3 and XCode 4. They make use of xcodebuild and a couple of external tools such as [appledoc](http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp/) and produces a distributable (versioned) DMG file if successful.

You can use these scripts if you like or just take a look to see how they work and get ideas for your own.

Comment: Actually I meant it the other way round: I want XCode to call make instead of having to set up everything within XCode again. (The project is complex and the Makefiles are used cross-platform.) Thanks for your answer, I hope it helped me to add detail to my question.

Comment: Ok, I remember setting up targets in XCode3 which ran command lines. Just right click on your target and add a run shell script phase. Then you can get it to run any shell command you like. I think there may even been shell script targets you can add as well.

Comment: Thanks, that was the right approach: Under target, I've added a run shell script phase which just includes the call to make. Then I deleted compile, link and copy phase since these tasks are handled by Makefile. Now I can build from XCode3 and see compile errors in my code.